# Custom group and average in SQL query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a question about SQL queries, can I do the following case using Postgres:

1- if I have millions of rows, each row has two columns "Date and Value"

2- I want to group each 1000 rows and return the "Date and avgValue(1000 rows)"

Example of my dataset:

```
Date | Value
2010 | 4
2011 | 2
2012 | 6
2013 | 8
2014 | 6
2015 | 4
2016 | 4
2017 | 3
2018 | 5
....
```

if i want to group each three rows by calculating the average of value column then the output should be like this:

```
Date      | Value
2010-2012 |  (4+2+6)/3
2013-2015 |  (8+6+4)/3
2016-2018 |  (4+3+5)/3
```

Thanks all

Comment: what is date of 1000 rows?

Comment: average of the value column

Comment: your response doesn't maka sense please add example input and output to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that

Comment: Generally when asking questions of this nature it is always good to provide input and output data, there was no way we could guess that you wanted to get that date range out.  Also it is helpful to set up sample schema on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Thanks i will do that next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to group by date, and within each date, group arbitrarily into batches of 1000 rows, and calculate the average of value in that group.

```
SELECT 
    date,
    rn,
    avg(value)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        date,
        value,
        row_number() OVER(partition by date) / 1000 as rn
    FROM 
        schema.table
) a
GROUP BY date,rn
```

The key here is the `row_number()` bit, which creates a variable which increments by row. We use OVER(partition by date) which means the counter will start again for each value of date.

We then divide this by 1000, so that each block of 1000 rows for each date will have the same value for `rn`. We then group by date & rn, to get the desired output.

What this query returns is one row per 1000 rows per date, with the average Value of that block.

Comment: Thanks very much, but I just edited the question to make it more clear, please review it and let me know if that's what your solution do

Comment: there is enough in this answer to figure out how to do it.  use min(date) and max(date) to build your range.  Combine them to be a string and then do a group by that date range string column.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by any expression, in your case you need to add a row number, then calculate the groups based on row number using division. note that you need to order also your date column otherwise you will have a strange results.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9b773f/9/0